# Client side load balancing (Ribbon) and Service Discovery (Eureka) on PaaS cloud (PCF)

Tags: cloud, microservices, netflix-eureka, cloud-foundry, netflix-ribbon

Currently we deploy our application to Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF), which operates in a Platform as a Service (PaaS) model.

It means whenever we deploy an app to PCF, PCF automatically (apart from the other actions it does) sets up a load balancer forwarding requests to the desired number of the instances it automatically provisioned.

Having that in mind, is it possible to use a client side load balancer such as Ribbon in a PaaS cloud, so that the clients of your app will reach out directly to the instances running your app, not to the load balancer? If yes, what are the benefits?

One more related question, if all my services follow the same naming convention e.g. `myapp-service` and therefore are available under `https://myapp-service.cfapps.io` is there any benefit of setting up a Service Discovery service (e.g. Eureka) in a PaaS cloud?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Having that in mind, is it possible to use a client side load balancer such as Ribbon in a PaaS cloud, so that the clients of your app will reach out directly to the instances running your app, not to the load balancer? If yes, what are the benefits?

You certainly could.  If you're using the route mapped to your app on PCF, you'd just have a client side load balancer with one server in it so it's not really adding any benefit.

Where you'd see more benefit is if you're using a client side load balancer and Cloud Foundry's Container to Container networking.  With C2C, you can talk directly to other apps.  The registry is needed in this case, so you can locate your service apps.

This blog post walks through a basic example of using SCS & C2C (it's for PWS, but should work on any PCF environment with C2C).

https://content.pivotal.io/blog/building-spring-microservices-with-cloud-foundrys-new-container-networking-stack

> One more related question, if all my services follow the same naming convention e.g. myapp-service and therefore are available under https://myapp-service.cfapps.io is there any benefit of setting up a Service Discovery service (e.g. Eureka) in a PaaS cloud?

I think the question is how does your app find `myapp-service.cfapps.io`?  If you have one app that's consuming one service, it's not too hard to have the app configured with the URL or perhaps to pass it in through an env variable or even a user provided, bound service.  Problem solved.

When you start to get lots of services, where "lots" is an arbitrarily large number, this get's to be a pain to manage.  When you hit that point, using a service registry will make life easier.  Not to say you can't use a service registry with the one app / one service scenario, it's just probably not as big of an advantage.

The other advantage of using a service registry is with C2C networking, as I mentioned above.  In that case, you need something to locate your services on the container network.  The SCS registry will do that.

For what it's worth, if you're on a pretty recent version of CF, there is actually platform provided service discovery via DNS.  If available, this could also be used to locate your service instances.  See here for details.

https://www.cloudfoundry.org/blog/polyglot-service-discovery-container-networking-cloud-foundry/

Comment: `If you're using the route mapped to your app on PCF, you'd just have a client side load balancer with one server in it so it's not really adding any benefit.` - you mean the client will access the load balancer setup by PCF? (My application runs on more than 1 instance). I understand that with C2C the clients will be able to directly communicate with the containers running the app instead of going through the LB, but what is the benefit of doing that?

Comment: `you mean the client will access the load balancer setup by PCF?` -> Yes.  The client side LB, won't balance anything because it will have one server, which is the route for your app.  When it requests resources from that route, it will go to the PCF LB which will in turn balance across all of your app instances.

Comment: `I understand that with C2C the clients will be able to directly communicate with the containers running the app instead of going through the LB, but what is the benefit of doing that?` -> Mostly latency.  Requests go direct from one app to another, so they don't have to go through the external LB & gorouter.  It also simplifies things, so you don't have issues with timeouts, stale connections and other LB related "fun".

Comment: Thank you Daniel very much.

Comment: Daniel I have asked another PCF related question, would appreciate your help there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290854/enable-container-to-container-networking-between-all-the-apps-in-the-space